# Transfer different chunks of data to client systems using python

Tags: python

Well i want to transfer different chunks of data to client machine , by different i mean the data sent could be either code or a particular function , i have used basic socket program in order to transfer the content , but how do i make the client system help differentiate between these contents , i am aware of the concept of metadata, but dont know how to apply it in here .

Example :
This following is the basic psuedo code on how it has to work

```
Server side : 
# basic socket program
> conn.send(data)

Slave side:
#basic socket program
> d = conn.recv(1024)
> if d is code:  execute the code 
> else:  store the data
```

Comment: Can you explain your scenario better? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: What does metadata have to do with serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your simply looking to serialize python objects.

Look at the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) (and cPickle) module. Pickle is the python serialization format, which will allow you to transfer python objects as strings. Make sure to take note of [what can, and can't be pickled](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) as well.

If your client needs to differentiate between data and code, you need to have something in your protocol which distinguishes them. A simple example would be to send your data using json. You could put the strings into dictionaries, and differentiate them by key:

```
'{"function": "def foo():\\n    print foo"}'
'{"data": "this is my data"}'
```

Comment: the problem is i am using smae DS to transfer different data . ie. the code is also sent as a string and "code" to be executed , which basically is a function is also transfered as a string , in receiving end , the client will not be able to differentiate since its constantly pooling the data from server .